# Swift: Index out of range (for)

Tags: swift

I am trying to do challange, but i stumbled on error, that my index is out of range. I do not know what can be the problem.

I tried anything that came to my mind. Thanks for any help.

```swift
func countApplesAndOranges(s: Int, t: Int, a: Int, b: Int, apples: [Int], oranges: [Int]) -> Void {
    var positionApples : [Int] = apples
    var positionOranges : [Int] = oranges


    for i in positionApples {
        positionApples[i] += a //This line
    }

    for i in positionOranges {
        positionOranges[i] += b //This line
    }

    var hitApples : Int = 0
    var hitOranges : Int = 0

    for i in positionApples {
        if i >= s && i <= t {
            hitApples += 1
        }
    }
    for i in positionOranges {
        if i >= s && i <= t {
            hitOranges += 1
        }
    }
    print(hitApples)
    print(hitOranges)
}
```

Array apples and oranges should copy to positionApples and positionOranges. Then to each item in the array, value should be added, but that just throws runtime error.

Comment: But `i` isn't an index into the array, it's a value *in* the array.

Comment: Swift is meant to be an expressive language. That said, I would rethink your parameter names. The next person who comes along is going to ask, "Hmm...what's `s/t/a/b`?" Index out of range is telling you you're looking for something at in index that ain't there. If you clean up your parameter names, I'm happy to take a crack at it when I can figure out what you're trying to do.

Comment: Variables s/t/a/b is not named by me. I am trying to add a specific number to all values in array, but I must be making some stupid mistake.
`positionApples[i] += a` and `positionOranges[i] += b`

Comment: Thank you rmaddy, I see it. I do not know how I managed to write that.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the value of `apples` is `[2, 4, 6, 8]` then the code

```
for i in positionApples {
    print(i)
}
```

prints the **elements** 2, 4, 6, 8 and not the **indices** 0, 1, 2, 3 so in the second iteration of

```
for i in positionApples {
    positionApples[i] += a //This line
}
```

`i` is 4 but the end index is actually 3 and the code will .

---

If you need the loop index *enumerate* the array

```
for (index, element) in positionApples.enumerated() {
    print(index, element)
}
```

Comment: you mean offset element (enumerated doesn't return the index)

Answer (score 0):

Let say, we call this method as shown below.

```
countApplesAndOranges(s: 3, t: 3, a: 3, b: 3, apples: [1,2,3], oranges: [4,5,6])
```

In the below code, possible value of `i` in the for loop is 1,2,3. But the actual indices of positionApples can be 0,1,2 only. When it tries to access array of index=3, it throws

> "Fatal error: Index out of range"

```
for i in positionApples {
    positionApples[i] += a //This line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you wanted to do.

```swift
for i in 0 ..< positionApples.count {
    positionApples[i] += a
}
```

This way, you can modify each element in the array.